# YAML.load raise exception: RangeError: bignum too big to convert into `long'

Tags: ruby

I have this YAML string:

```
---
lease: 2014-09-26 05:20:39.616606000 Z
createtime: 2014-09-20 05:20:39.616606000 Z
leased_at: 2014-09-23 00:22:37.052173269 +08:00
```

My ruby version is pretty old, but I cannot upgrade it, my version is:

```
ruby 1.9.1p376 (2009-12-07 revision 26041) [i686-linux]
```

When I try to use `YAML.load` to parse the above string:

```
YAML.load(str) # where str is above string
```

I got the following error:

```
irb(main):028:0> YAML.load(str)
RangeError: bignum too big to convert into `long'
    from /build/toolchain/lin32/ruby-1.9.1-p376/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:133:in `utc'
    from /build/toolchain/lin32/ruby-1.9.1-p376/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:133:in `node_import'
    from /build/toolchain/lin32/ruby-1.9.1-p376/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:133:in `load'
    from /build/toolchain/lin32/ruby-1.9.1-p376/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:133:in `load'
    from (irb):28
```

I believe the problem is those times contain too long millisecond part. Given I cannot upgrade my ruby, how can I successfully parse about YAML string?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp directly on your YAML string for match with your time pattern and truncate milliseconds.

More about regexp in ruby: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html